# MySQL add row from child row if not exists in parent table with error 1452

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1452

I have two tables like these:

```
CREATE TABLE parentTable(
pID    INT,
ArtNr  INT,
Name   VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
UNIQUE KEY (ArtNr)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE childTable(
cID       INT,
ArtNr     INT,
Name      VARCHAR(50),
UNIQUE KEY (ArtNr),
FOREIGN KEY (ArtNr) REFERENCES parentTable(ArtNr) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now the problem which I have is, that if there is an entry in my childTable with a ArtNr which is not found in my parentTable, I get this error message:

```
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sys`.`childTable`, CONSTRAINT `childTable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ArtNr`) REFERENCES `parentTable` (`ArtNr`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

What I want to do is, to add the row if the entry in the childTable is not found in my parentTable. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What do you want? You have created foreign key constraint. And now, trying to avoid it.

Comment: No. I just want to add the missing entries into the parentTable

Comment: Have a look at the answer (part 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use server variable FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS to on/off foreign key value checking.

For example:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

// ...
// your script...
// ...

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

More information - [foreign_key_checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks).

---

You can find missing entries using this query -

```
SELECT c.* FROM child c
LEFT JOIN parent p
  ON p.id = c.id
WHERE p.id IS NULL;
```

Then insert these set of ID into parent table. Do it with a help of [INSERT..SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement.

Comment: thanks, but this doesn´t help to add the missing entries

Comment: Show your full script.

Comment: thank you.. with this statement i found the missing entries